# Can we have triggers on database level using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am learning a Sql course on Udemy; the instructor is using MSSQL and says that we can have triggers on the database level as well as table level. 
Now, for the database lever here is the code that he suggested:

```
Create trigger demo on database
after create_table
as 
begin
print "create is not allowed"
roll back transaction
End
Go
```

So, I copy and pasted this code in MySql. But, got errors!
First of all, I get syntax error because of `on` (on database); if I remove it, get syntax error on database. 
I googled to see whether we can have triggers on database level or not, did not find anything. 
Now, my question from experts is that if this is doable in MySql or this is something only for MSSQL?

Thanks,

Comment: @RaymondNijland In the link you posted, there is an example for how to make a trigger at the database and server level.

Comment: Oeps indeed @dfundako ok then triggers on database level are possible in MSSQL.. i know for a fact triggers on database level are not possible with MySQL.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server have two completely different origins, capabilities, and to a large degree, command-set. SQL is just a vague family of languages that share characteristics and are absolutely not inter-compatible. *Always* check the MySQL documentation when using MySQL before hammering in random SQL code. The same holds true for SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks everyone, so the code does not have any equivalent in MySql?

Comment: Besides looking into your SQL code your beter off handling this with privileges

Comment: @RaymondNijland can I have an example of privileges? Thx

Comment: i asumming that SQL server trigger code should block creating tables within a database?..  in MySQL you can use privileges which user can create tables

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr;**
If you are learning a course on SQL Server, you need to do the training on SQL Server.

**Why?**

Because while SQL does have a standard (ANSI-SQL), every RDBMS (Relational Data Base Management System) use a different dialect of SQL.
SQL Server use T-SQL, while MySql uses another sql dialect (apparently, also called MySql).
(Oracle use PL/SQL, other databases use other dialects, you get the picture).

This means that Syntax that works for one RDBMS is not guaranteed to work on another RDBMS.

Create Trigger statements are highly vendor-specific, meaning that for each SQL dialect the syntax will probably be different.

Further more, from a quick search, seems like [MySql has not yet implemented DDL triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2418) - As you can see in the link, the status is Un-Assigned.

BTW, 
not all dialects of SQL actually follows the standard, (In fact, I'm not sure any of them follow the standard completely) - so even if you only use ANSI-SQL, you might not get the same results from different database vendors.